# What to do when VBA Error handler causes error?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am currently working on a larger program which may throw an error at some point. So I added an error handler for that case. The primary goal of which is to close the opened excel workbook `wbk` so that I don't get too many excel-applications running in the background. As I don't know, which part of the program may cause the error, I don't know the state of `wbk` and whether it is open or not. I tried adding a check for `Nothing` but `wbk is Nothing` seems to be false at that point. With the following code I will get `The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable (Error 462)` when the error handler is called:

**Error Handler**

```
On Error Resume Next
resp = MsgBox(prompt:="Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten! " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Soll versucht werden weiter fortzufahren?" & _
    vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Fehlercode: " & str(Err.Number) & " entstanden durch " & Err.Source & Chr(13) & Err.Description, _
    Buttons:=vbCritical + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
    title:="Unbekannter Fehler", _
    HelpFile:=Err.HelpFile, _
    Context:=Err.HelpContext)

If Not wbk Is Nothing Then
    wbk.Close False
End If

If resp = vbNo Then Exit Sub
Resume Next
```

Afaik, I shouldn't even get an error because of the `On Error Resume Next`. **Edit:** It should since "The error hander is still active when the second error occurs, and therefore the second error is not trapped by the On Error statement." - [source](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm)

TL;DR: `wbk` should be closed in error handling if it is open, but it throws an error.

**Edit:**
I force an error in order to call the error handler. Said error does only happen in the second execution so the `wbk` value is set normally, then the workbook is closed and the program is called again and the error is forced before `wbk` is initialized again.

Comment: If you get an error despite OERN then you likely have "Break on all errors" set in your VBA options.  Try "Break in class module" instead.

Comment: I had the option set to "On uncaught errors", setting it to "Break in class module" unfortunately does not help.

Comment: This is the best guide to error handling in VBA - worth a read.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've read the guide and it explained why I get the second error: "The error handler is still active when the second error occurs, and therefore the second error is not trapped by the On Error statement." Do you know any other way to _try_ to close the workbook just in case it is open? @TimWilliams

Comment: You can try looking for it by iteration between the open Workbooks. `Dim W As Workbook, boolFound As Boolean`   `For Each W in Workbooks`  `If W.Name = "your Wb name" Then`  `Set wbk = W`  `boolFound = True` `Exit For`  `Next` Then, after you checked if it has been found you can use: `If boolFound Then wbk.Close False`.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what the fix might be without seeing the whole method.

Comment: You're right but since the whole program is really lengthy and I was looking for a solution independent from wbk's value, I decided not to share it. So the solution I found is not really what I was looking for but it works.

Answer (score 0):

During the second execution, `wbk` has whatever value it has after `wbk.Close` was called, this is not `Nothing`. I did now explicitly set `Set wbk = Nothing` after closing and the error does no longer happen, due to the Nothing check above.

Btw. I changed the responses around since it doesn't really make sense to close the workbook when the code is resumed.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, I always Set any Object to Nothing when I'm done with it. I know I've had issues in the past but think these were if I didn't let the routine finish (eg stepping through a routine and stopped or entered debug mode and stopped.